# Object Relationship Tree

Tags: apex, sobject, scratch-org, schema

I am currently trying to figure out how to elicit an object relationship tree from Salesforce, so I can export test data to use in my Scratch-Orgs.  Basically what I want to do is poll to produce a data structure via Apex or other some other means that defines all related sObjects types for each sObject type, and the respective field(s) used to traverse many-to-one/one-to-many (or both) for each relationship.  Any ideas on how best to achieve this?

Comment: What tool are you proposing to use to export the data? Salesforce's object model is not a directed acyclic graph, and features like polymorphic lookups make this problem very hard to solve in the fully general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looked around for bits and pieces and put the following together:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/SchemaApi/*')
global with sharing class ObjectRelApi  {

@HttpGet    
global static void GetSchemaInfo() {

    // Defaulting
    Map<String,Map<String,String>> objectRelationships = new Map<String,Map<String,String>>();
    Map<String,List<String>> objectFields = new Map<String,List<String>>();
    Map<String,Object> finalMap = new Map<String,Object>();

    // Collect all objects
    Map<String, SObjectType> allSObjectTypes = Schema.getGlobalDescribe();

    // Each object type
    for (string key : allSObjectTypes.keySet()) {

        // Defaulting
        Map<String,String> fieldChildMap = new Map<String,String>();
        List<String> fieldNames = new List<String>();

        // Obtain child schema details
        string objectTypeName = allSObjectTypes.get(key).getDescribe().getName();
        List<ChildRelationship> childRelationships = allSObjectTypes.get(key).getDescribe().getChildRelationships();            

        // Each child relationship
        for (ChildRelationship thisChildRelationship : childRelationships) {

            // Record childhood entry
            string accrossFieldName = thisChildRelationship.getField().getDescribe().getName();
            string forChildObjectTypeName = thisChildRelationship.getChildSObject().getDescribe().getName();
            fieldChildMap.put(accrossFieldName, forChildObjectTypeName);

        }

        // Append result
        objectRelationships.put(objectTypeName, fieldChildMap); 

        // Object field schema details          
        Map<String, Schema.SobjectField> fieldMap = allSObjectTypes.get(key).getDescribe().fields.getMap();

        // Each field
        for (string fieldKey : fieldMap.keySet()) {

            // Record field entry
            fieldNames.add(fieldKey);

        }

        // Append result
        objectFields.put(objectTypeName, fieldNames);
    }

    // Add to final map
    finalMap.put('FieldSet', objectFields);
    finalMap.put('RelationshipSet', objectRelationships);

    // Return result
    RestContext.response.responseBody = Blob.valueOf(JSON.serializePretty(finalMap));

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your best option migt be the pilot of [MetadataComponentDependency](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_metadatacomponentdependency.htm) REST resource in Tooling API. Read the linked doc and the associated Trailblazer group for more info.